# What are the data differences between live.dbpedia.org, dbpedia.org, and the dbpedia data dump?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, linked-data

I understand that live.dbpedia.org is closer to a real time version of the dbpedia.org data, but that invites the question, how often is the regular dbpedia extraction/update process run? How often are the data dumps updated? Also, it's been said that the main endpoint incorporates other datasets in addition to what is extracted from Wikipedia.

What are the differences in data between dbpedia.org, live.dbpedia.org, and the data dumps?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  In "some of it doesn't behave the same" doesnt' tell us what differences you're seeing.  [DBpedia Live](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaLive) says, "DBpedia is considered the Semantic Web mirror of Wikipedia. Over time, Wikipedia articles are revised, which makes the data in DBpedia outdated. The main objective of DBpedia Live is to keep DBpedia always in synchronization with Wikipedia."  Is there more to it than that?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor there is certainly more to the question. so I've tried to rewrite the entire question. perhaps now that it has been updated, you can see what I'm confused about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some research on DBpedia for a project and I am going to share what I found out:

- http://dbpedia.org/sparql: This endpoint is using most of the Datasets from [DBpedia Downloads 2014](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2014) ([WayBackMachineLink](https://web.archive.org/web/20141003104455/http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads2014?)). For the complete list of the Datasets it is using and a little more information go to this site: [Datasets Loaded 2014](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DatasetsLoaded2014) ([WayBackMachineLink](https://web.archive.org/web/20140928173834/http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DatasetsLoaded2014)). So how often are the Downloads updated? See the [changelog](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Changelog) of the Downloads.
- http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql: This endpoint is using the data from [DBpedia live](http://live.dbpedia.org/). If you take a look at the [live changesets](http://live.dbpedia.org/changesets/) you can see that sometimes it is updated at least every hour, sometimes like in September2014 just once a month. DBpedia is saying about this:

> Q: The live-updates of DBpedia (changesets) have the structure year/month/day/hour/xxxx.nt.gz. What does it mean if there are some gaps in between, e.g. a folder for some hour is missing?
>
> A: This means that the service was down at that time.

And [DBpedia live - 3. new features](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaLive?v=19kc#h156-4) ([WayBackMachineLink](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006013902/http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaLive?v=19kc#h156-4))says:

> 5.*Development of synchronization tool*: The synchronization tool enables a DBpedia Live mirror to stay in synchronization with our live endpoint. It downloads the changeset files sequentially, decompresses them, and integrates them with another DBpedia Live mirror.

So I think if you're synchron with the live-endpoint when applying the changeset, the live endpoint is also applying the changeset.